# Panel's Children as ComboBox's ItemsSource

Tags: xaml, combobox, uwp, children, itemssource

In WPF I can do use a Panel's Children collection as the ItemsSource of a ComboBox:

[WPF Panel's Children as ComboBox's ItemsSource](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTQZ0.png)

But in UWP this throws exception: "The parameter is incorrect." & vbCrLf

The Code-XAML:

```
<StackPanel>

<StackPanel Name="Panel1">

<TextBox Text="Item 1" />

<TextBox Text="Item 2" Margin="0,10,0,0" />

</StackPanel>

<ComboBox Margin="0,10,0,0" Name="Combo1" >
<ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" />
</DataTemplate>
</ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>

</StackPanel>
```

The Code-Behind:

```
Private Sub MainWindow_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded

Combo1.ItemsSource = Panel1.Children

End Sub
```

How can i achieve the same goal at UWP?

Comment: Why do you want to do that at all? Please explain what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: I need this to change some properties from an objetcs, i need select the objects than are in canvas to change the values, but i want that it be the same instance, below combobox there some fields as width, height, X and Y Positions, Etc.

Comment: I guess that the exception is because two controls (objects) can't be twice in design, (1 in panel and 1 in the combobox)

Comment: Better use an ItemsControl and a ComboBox and bind the ItemsSource property of both to a collection of data items.

Comment: I have been doing tests and did what did you said, in wpf do fine but in uwp not, can't have a control in both itemssource and combobox at same time, and panel neither

Comment: That's why I said collection of data items. This shouldn't be a conrol class, bt instead some anstract representation of the control's relevant data. Then bind a control in each ItemTemplate of the ComboBox and the ItemsControl to this data.

Comment: Itemscontrol, sorry